# Converting Word Doc to PDF in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

Working on a page that displays the Standard Operating Procedures (SOP) and allows a non-Admin to download the SOP in a PDF file. Clients decided they didn't want admins to be limited to uploading just PDF files, and they want the option to upload .doc and .docx files. I need the download link to produce a PDF though.

Right now uploading either a .doc/.docx or a .pdf will display as I want it to using the Google Viewer. But when I attempt to download the test file it cant be opened if the files uploaded was a .doc/.docx. I've looked over this, and I'm sure I'm missing something stupid.

I'm using **cfdocumnet** as was suggested on another question.

Download link:

```
<cfoutput>
   <li class="active">                 
      <ahref="/files/SOP/SOP.pdf" 
        download="SOP.pdf" target="_blank">Download SOP</a>
   </li>
</cfoutput>
```

Check for Admin (variable is created elsewhere) and form to upload file:

```
<cfif isAdmin>
  <h3>Upload New SOP</h3>
  <cfparam name="form.fileUpload" default="">
  <cftry>
    <cffile action="upload"
        fileField="fileUpload"
        destination="#expandPath('.')#\files\SOP\"
        accept="application/pdf,
             application/msword,
             application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,
             application/x-tika-msoffice"
        nameconflict="OVERWRITE">

    <cfset fileName=CFFILE.serverfile>

    <cfdocument 
          format="PDF"
          srcfile="#expandPath('.')#\files\SOP\#fileName#"
          filename="#expandPath('.')#\files\SOP\SOP.pdf"
          overwrite="YES">
    </cfdocument>
    <p>Thank you, your file has been uploaded.</p>
    <cfoutput>#fileName#</cfoutput>

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
      <input type="file" name="fileUpload"/>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File"/>
    </form>
    <cfcatch type="any">
      <!--- file is not written to disk if error is thrown  --->
      <!--- prevent zero length files --->
      <cfif FindNoCase("No data was received in the uploaded", cfcatch.message)>
        <p>No data was received in the uploaded file.</p>
      <!--- prevent invalid file types --->
      <cfelseif FindNoCase("The MIME type or the Extension of the uploaded file", cfcatch.message)>
        <p>Invalid file type. Please upload file as a PDF or Word Doc</p>
      <!--- prevent empty form field --->
      <cfelseif FindNoCase("did not contain a file.", cfcatch.message)>
        <p>Please seclect a PDF to upload.</p>
      <!---all other errors --->
      <cfelse>
        <p>Unhandled File Upload Error</p>
        <cflog type="Error" file="#application.applicationname#_dcnsopupload_error" text="#cfcatch.Message# - #cfcatch.Detail#" />
        <cfoutput>#cfcatch.Detail#</cfoutput>
      </cfif>
    </cfcatch>
  </cftry>
</cfif>
```

And on a side note, because I want the downloadable .pdf to be the given name "SOP.pdf" is there a way I can delete the user-uploaded file after renaming it and converting it? Just so there aren't 30 different outdated SOP documents on the server.

Comment: What version of ColdFusion?

Comment: Also, `cfif isAdmin` is an unreliable way to limit functionality. https://www.petefreitag.com/item/834.cfm

Comment: Also, what version of Word are these files being created in?

Comment: ColdFusion 11

The cfif isAdmin is pulling from code elsewhere in the file that uses the login credentials of the user and double checking the database to verify role. Not using "session." for anything. 

The word files being created will be done so in Word 2003 - Office 365. I uploaded a file created in Word 365. Possible Openoffice. I'm not totally sure. I pulled the information under the 'accept' tag from a co-worker.

Comment: Do you have [OpenOffice installed](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/installing/installing-integrated-technologies.html)? It's required to convert docx to pdf. Regarding file downloads, don't use a static file name like "SOP.pdf" or multiple threads may end up overwriting each other's files under load. Instead, create a unique file name using createUUID() or getTempFile(). Then use `cfheader` and [`cfcontent`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-c/cfcontent.html) to display a file download with the desired file name.

Comment: @Ageax I'm not entirely sure on the OpenOffice thing. Other pages on the site use the cfdocument to convert .doc/.docx to .PDF, so I'm guessing so. And thanks for the static file advice. I'll set that up differently!

Comment: Are you getting an error? Because the form/upload code looks wrong to me. Due to the cfparam, it may be running trying to run the upload/conversion *before* a file is even submitted. Try creating a simpler example containing only the form and upload - no error handling.  `<cfif structKeyExists(FORM, "fileUpload")> put upload/cfdocument code here <cfelse> <form ...> display form here </form> </cfif>`

Comment: Actually, right now I am getting an error. The other day it was running fine, except I couldn't view the PDF once I uploaded a .doc/.docx. With nothing changed now it's throwing the 'Unhandled File Upload Error' and giving back 'The files upload action requires forms to use enctype="multipart/form-data". '

I'll try moving this around and post the results. Thanks!

Comment: UPDATE: Okay, that fixed that issue. @Ageax, you da bomb. Now I guess I just need to  wrap this back with some error handling and see what happens. But this gives me a new jumping point.

Comment: Sounds good! Actually, re-reading the whole thread again I take back what I said about static file names. You probably *do* want to use a static file name here. The reason being you'll probably only have a *single* copy of the SOP on the server at any one time. (I was mistakenly thinking this was a dynamically generated download - i.e. different for each user - so you'd  need unique file names to avoid conflicts, but that's not the case here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form upload code looks wrong. Due to the `cfparam`, it's probably trying run the upload/conversion *before* the form is even submitted. Remove the `cfparam` and use [structKeyExists()](https://cfdocs.org/structkeyexists) to verify the file field was submitted before trying to process it.

Try a simplified example first, with only the form and upload code (no error handling).

```
<!--- If file was uploaded, process it ---> 
<cfif structKeyExists(FORM, "fileUpload")> 

    <cffile action="upload"
        fileField="fileUpload"
        destination="#GetTempDirectory()#"
        accept="application/pdf,application/msword,
        application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,
        application/x-tika-msoffice"
        nameconflict="makeunique">

    <cfset savedFilePath = cffile.serverDirectory &"/"& cffile.serverFile>

    <!--- 
        more file validation here ... 
    --->

    <!--- convert file ---> 
    <cfdocument format="PDF"
        srcfile="#savedFilePath#"
        filename="#expandPath('.')#\files\SOP\SOP.pdf"
        overwrite="YES">
    </cfdocument>

    <!--- cleanup temp file --->
    <cfif fileExists(uploadedFile)>
        <cfset fileDelete(uploadedFile)>
    </cfif>

<!--- Otherwise, just display the form ---> 
<cfelse>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="fileUpload"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File"/>
    </form>
</cfif>
```

Also, though a bit dated, some of these tips on securing file uploads are still valid (such as not uploading files to the web root):

- http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/File_Uploads/
- https://www.petefreitag.com/item/701.cfm

Comment: The fileDelete(uploadedFIle) was what I was just sorting out yesterday trying to clean up the client uploaded files. This is pretty much what I ended up with that got everything working. Now just waiting to see what the client thinks (and what all they decide they want to change about how it works).

Thanks again!